# jquery paginating php return data

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I am using this jquery to fetch paginated data from php file from server. The php file generates the pagination and also returns the data associated with these in json format. my pagination data is returned as a list of li tags, i use this to replace the already existing bootstrap pagination in the html file

initially, this is what is generated by my php file

```
<ul>
<li class="active"><a>1 </a></li>
<li><a href="#2">2</a></li>
</ul>
```

When i click on 2, its gets the data next pagination shown

```
<ul><li><a href="#1">1</a></li>
<li class="active"><a>2 </a></li></ul>
```

Now when i click on 1 to get data for 1, the jquery events dosen't fire, the jquery code

```
$("#pagination li a").click(function(e) { 
    debugger;
    e.preventDefault();

    var start=$(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
    var msgDiv=$('#messages');
    var pagDiv=$("#pagination ul");
    try{
        $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
            beforeSend: function() {showLoading(msgDiv);},
            timeout:10000,
            type: "post", // GET or POST
            url: "./process-messages.php", // the file to call
            dataType:'json',
            data: {start:start}, // get the form data
            success: function(response) { // on success..
                if(response.status!='error'){
                   msgDiv.html(response.data); // update the DIV
                   pagDiv.html(response.page); // update the DIV
                }else{
                    msgDiv.html(response.data); // update the DIV
                }
            },
            error: function() { // on success..
                showGeneralError(msgDiv);
            }
        }); 
    }catch (e){
        console.log(e);
    }

});
```

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `on` for dynamic contents. Try

```
$(document).on('click', '#pagination li a', function() {
```

> Event delegation is an event handling technique where, instead of
>   attaching event handlers directly to every element you want to listen
>   to events on, you attach a single event handler to a parent element of
>   those elements to listen for events occurring on it’s descendant
>   elements.

Comment: thank you very much, but why does it firs for 1 and not for 2?

Comment: You should take some time to research on `event delegation`. This article might be helpful http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Comment: i have jquery 1.8 documentation, i couldn't find anything related to delgation except notable that .delegate is no longer supported in 1.7+

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method. For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to use event delegation. Reference: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 1):

You are binding the click event to the existing elements, when the page is loaded. When the list gets replaced, the events are deleted along with the old elements. What you need is either to call the initialization function again when the AJAX returns (a bit clumpsy) or better to use `.on()` like this:

```
$("#pagination-container").on("click", "li a", function() {
    // same as your handler
});
```

Beware though that the `pagination-container` must remain in the page, i.e. *not* updated through AJAX:

```
<div id="pagination-container">
    <ul>
        ...pagination as in your code
    </ul>
</div>
```

I assume the AJAX returns the `<ul>...</ul>` stuff.

Comment: thank you, you answer worked too, i wish stack could allow to make multiple correct answers